# Is there a way to reset state immediately after it has changed in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, animation, state

I am attempting to perform an animation to one of my components each time the data changes, so that the data slides in from the left. So each time the state of the component changes, I am adding an animation to it.

The problem with this, is that once the animation is added, it stays there, so the component only renders the animation once. Ideally what I want to do is render the animation then immediately remove it from state, so it can be added again for the next component.

As you can see below, the code i'm using is a pretty simple if statement to check if the animation is present, if it isn't then it will be added. I also tried a setTimeout to remove the animation after 1.8 seconds, but this would cause problems if the user is switching between components quickly.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){

     if(prevProps.name !== this.props.name){
            if(this.state.animation !== "slideIn 2s linear"){
                this.setState({
                    animation: "slideIn 2s linear"
                })
                // setTimeout(() => { 
                //     this.setState({ animation: " " }) 
                // }, 1800);
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    animation: " "
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

This is where I am using the animation state.

```
<ImageTextContainer style = {{animation: this.state.animation}}>
```

I appreciate this is perhaps not the best approach, so any fresh ideas are more than welcome!

All help is much appreciate, thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, have you considered using React Transition Group? For animations based on state SwitchTransition Component might be worth a try.
see: http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/

Comment: thanks @NickG I'll have a look into that

Answer (score 2):

You can create a this.timeout property then assign setTimeout to that property which then you can clearTimeout(this.timeout)

```
if(prevProps.name !== this.props.name) {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout)
    this.setState({
       animation: "slideIn 2s linear"
    })
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => { 
      this.setState({ animation: " " }) 
    }, 1800);
  ...
```

This way it should not cause any problem for your next slide.

Comment: Thanks that does help, but I still have a problem where the timeout isn't reset immediately, so the class won't be removed if i switch between component too quickly